# How to choose a specific nft to transfer

Tags: anchor, nft, spl-token-program

I'm minting a lot of spl-tokens which is 1 decimal. Let's assume that each nft have different metadata. So how can I choose a specific nft to transfer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each NFT has a mint address. Since NFTs are tokens with a max supply of 1. The mint for each NFT will be unique to that NFT.

Comment: Can you give me example code? I only find this function spl_token::instruction::transfer(token_program_id, source_pubkey, destination_pubkey, authority_pubkey, signer_pubkeys, amount) but there is no param tell me which nft to transfer like you said